# Tkinter - python 3 - overlapping grid of checkboxes from a loop within a loop

Tags: python, pandas, loops, tkinter, python-class

I have this code here that runs a window that looks like this:

[image: Original WIndow]

Once I click on one of those element buttons I get the isotope results shown here:

[image: Results with many isotopes]

But if I select another button I just get an overwrite of the checkboxes shown here:
[image: Overwritten results not refreshed frame]

I cannot for the life of me find a way to destroy the previous checkboxes before showing the results. I have tried a number of ways and I am pretty sure that this here [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49396207/tkinter-grid-overlapping) is the answer but I am not 100% sure if I need to split my results into a range and append the button lists accordingly. I am trying but I am new to front-end progamming. Does anyone know how to get this thing working??

Here is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import os
import pandas as pd

__location__ = os.path.realpath(
    os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.path.dirname(__file__)))


class AppTBL(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
        self.winfo_toplevel().title("Periodic Table of the Elements")
        self.topLabel = tk.Label(
            self, text="\n\n\n\nClick the element you would like information about.", font=20)
        self.topLabel.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=18)
        self.column1 = [
            ('H', 'Hydrogen', '\nAtomic # = 1\nAtomic Weight =1.01\nState = Gas\nCategory = Alkali Metals',),
            ('Li', 'Lithium', '\nAtomic # = 3\nAtomic Weight = 6.94\nState = Solid\nCategory = Alkali Metals'),
            ('Sod', 'Sodium', '\nAtomic # = 11\nAtomic Weight = 22.99\nState = Solid\nCategory = Alkali Metals'),
            ('K', 'Potassium', '\nAtomic # = 19\nAtomic Weight = 39.10\nState = Solid\nCategory = Alkali Metals'),
            ('Rb', 'Rubidium', '\nAtomic # = 37\nAtomic Weight = 85.47\nState = Solid\nCategory = Alkali Metals'),
            ('Cs', 'Cesium', '\nAtomic # = 55\nAtomic Weight = 132.91\nState = Solid\nCategory = Alkali Metals'),
            ('Fr', 'Francium', '\nAtomic # = 87\nAtomic Weight = 223.00\nState = Solid\nCategory = Alkali Metals')]
        r = 1
        c = 0
        for b in self.column1:
            self.elebtn = tk.Button(self,
                                    text=b[0],
                                    width=5,
                                    height=2,
                                    bg="grey",
                                    command=lambda text=b: [self.name(text[1]), self.thebtn(text[1]), self.isotopes(text[0]), self.isodestroy]).grid(row=r, column=c)
            r += 1
            if r > len(self.column1):
                r = 1
                c += 1
        self.infoLine = tk.Label(self, text="", justify='left')
        self.infoLine.grid(row=1, column=3, columnspan=10, rowspan=4)

    def name(self, text):
        self.topLabel.config(text=text)

    def info(self, text):
        self.infoLine.config(text=text)

    def thebtn(self, anything):
        thefile = os.path.join(__location__, 'thefile.txt')
        elementStr = []
        elementStr.append(anything)
        with open(thefile, 'w') as writeit:
            for each in elementStr:
                writeit.write(each)

    def isotopes(self, text):
        isofile = os.path.join(__location__, 'isotope.csv')
        text = text
        df = pd.read_csv(isofile, header=0)
        subset = df[df['element'] == text.upper()]
        subset = subset.astype({'isotope': int})
        subindex = subset.index
        numrows = len(subindex)
        r = 1
        c = 2
        r1 = 1
        c1 = 2
        for index, row in subset.iterrows():
            if numrows < 7:
                text = row['isotope']
                isobtn = tk.Checkbutton(self, text=text, width=3,
                                        height=1, fg='brown').grid(row=r, column=c)
                r += 1
                if r > len(self.column1):
                    r = 1
                    c += 1
            elif numrows >= 7:
                text = row['isotope']
                chkbtn = tk.Checkbutton(self, text=text, width=3,
                                        height=1, fg='brown').grid(row=r1, column=c1)
                r1 += 1
                if r1 > len(self.column1):
                    r1 = 1
                    c1 += 1

    def isodestroy(self):
        pass


def endit(gui_sys):
    # self.element_table_callback()
    pass


root = tk.Tk()
root.eval('tk::PlaceWindow . center')
a = AppTBL(root)
a.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
a.bind('<Destroy>', endit)
a.bind('<Button-1>', AppTBL.isodestroy)
a.mainloop()
```

Thanks in advance! I have been stuck on this for two days now and I am just losing my mind here.

> for isotopes.csv it will not work if you copy and paste code unless you add a csv file in the same directory.. here is a little bit for example if needed. You will need to turn it into a csv in notepad++ or notepad. I can also give the original file in a share drive if needed.

| element | isotope |
| --- | --- |
| H | 1 |
| H | 2 |
| H | 3 |
| H | 5 |
| H | 6 |
| H | 7 |
| HE | 10 |
| HE | 2 |
| HE | 3 |
| HE | 4 |
| HE | 5 |
| HE | 6 |
| HE | 7 |
| HE | 8 |
| HE | 9 |

The answer was:

```
        for child in self.winfo_children():
        if child.winfo_class() == 'Checkbutton':
            child.destroy()
```

But that also included taking the results from a run, appending it to its own table in a database. then calling it again in another function that I had to run twice. once before the button was clicked and once after.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the previous checkboxes before displaying the result for the next element, then there is such an option.
A widget has a method to get a list of all of its children, `widget.winfo_children()`.
You can create a container for checkboxes, such as a frame. And if necessary, remove all elements in the frame.

To see how this works, you can do the following:

in `def __init__`

```py
def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
    ...
    # self.infoLine = tk.Label(self, text="", justify='left')
    # self.infoLine.grid(row=1, column=3, columnspan=10, rowspan=4)
    self.frame = tk.Frame(self)
    self.frame.grid(row=1, column=3, columnspan=10, rowspan=4)
```

in `def isotopes`

```py
def isotopes(self, text):
    # destroy previous checkboxes
    for child in self.frame.winfo_children():
        child.destroy()
    ...
    for index, row in subset.iterrows():
        ...
            isobtn = tk.Checkbutton(self.frame, ...
        ...
            chkbtn = tk.Checkbutton(self.frame, ...
```

You may need to redesign the interface to fit the frame into the window.

Comment: Does not work at the moment but I am going to try and create another frame that it might fit into and have a frame within a frame.

Comment: This does not seem to work at all. I can see the list and it has a frame on it but it still shows the previous grids underneath. However, I did remove the self.infoline section thought because that was no longer being used at all so I am hoping I am getting closer.

Comment: The new frame does not line out with the same grid layout as the original no matter what I do.  I can upload the code for the main program if it will help since it connects to a sqlite db to get all the elements. But then it will not run in your editor if you copy and paste it.

Comment: Correct answer for me  was:


        for child in self.winfo_children():
            if child.winfo_class() == 'Checkbutton':
                child.destroy()

Comment: If you have no other checkboxes other than the ones you want to remove, you can remove all the checkboxes in the window.